# Karate framework - How to check conditional OR in match contains response

Tags: java, json, automated-tests, graphql, karate

I am trying to use a match contains to verify my schema response and data types and sometimes it returns a null and sometimes it will return a string, as an example.  I am trying the following but I am getting the assertion failed because it did not evaluate to true.

I am trying the following:

```
* match each $response.data.Results contains

        """
        {
        "providerID": '#number',
        "firstName": "#? _ == '#string' || _ == '#null'",
        "lastName": '#string',
        "mI": "#? _ == '#string' || _ == '#null'",
        "title": '#string',
        "name": '#string',
        "nameLFMT": '#string',
        "status": '#string',
        "specialties": '#array',
        "locations": '#array',
        "institutions": '#array',
        "acceptNewPatient": '#string',
        "imageUri": '#string',
        "nearestLatitude": '#number',
        "nearestLongitude": '#number'
        }

            """
```

The data returned for "firstName" for example is "firstName":null,

Prior to the match each I am sending this:

```
Scenario: SearchResults
  #Verify 200 response status returned
Given text query =
        """
     {
                  Results: getSearchResults(searchLatitude:"48.942833",
                        searchLongitude: "-119.984549",
                        providerType: "Primary Care Physicians",
                        sortBy: "distance",
                        maxDistance:"600",
                        skip: 0,
                        take: 10) {
                                        providerID
                                        firstName
                                        lastName
                                        mI
                                        title
                                        name
                                        nameLFMT
                                        status
                                        specialties
                                        locations
                                        institutions
                                        acceptNewPatient
                                        imageUri
                                        nearestLatitude
                                        nearestLongitude
                        }

    }

        """

And request { query: '#(query)' }
When method post
Then status 200
```

I am not defining the schema, I have yet to figure out how to do this so I am not sure if that is my issue.  I know this is probably how I should do this but I'm still learning.

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ok I see one problem here:

```
"firstName": "#? _ == '#string' || _ == '#null'"
```

That's not going to work. The part that follows the `#?` has to be a valid JavaScript expression. This may be hard to understand if you are not familiar with JS but `#string` and friends are specific to the Karate `match` keyword and *not* something that works in JavaScript.

So what the above line is doing is checking if the *value* of `firstName` is equal to the literal string `#string`.

Fortunately Karate has a solution: (refer doc for '[fuzzy matching](https://github.com/intuit/karate#fuzzy-matching)'):

```
"firstName": "##string"
```

Which is a convenience, the double `##` means 'optional' that will match for *both* a string or `null`.

EDIT: for advanced cases, please read this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/50350442/143475