# Is it possible to use karate 'match' inside conditional statement?

Tags: conditional-statements, karate

Find the example here.

```
def a = condition ? " karate match statement " : "karate match statement"
```

Is it possible to do something like this??

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is not recommended practice for tests because [tests should be deterministic](https://martinfowler.com/articles/nonDeterminism.html).

The right thing to do is:

- craft your request so that the response is 100% predictable. do not worry about code-duplication, this is [sometimes necessary for tests](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54126724/143475)
- ignore the dynamic data if it is not relevant to the `Scenario`
- use [conditional logic](https://github.com/intuit/karate#conditional-logic) to set "expected value" variables instead of complicating your `match` logic
- use [self-validation expressions](https://github.com/intuit/karate#self-validation-expressions) or [schema-validation expressions](https://github.com/intuit/karate#schema-validation) for specific parts of the JSON
- use the `if` keyword and [call a second feature file](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54528103/143475) - or you can even set the name of the file to call dynamically via a variable
- in some cases [`karate.abort()`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57413570/143475) can be used to conditionally skip / exit early

That said, if you really insist on doing this in the *same* flow, Karate allows you to do a `match` via JS in 0.9.6.RC4 onwards.

See this thread for details: https://github.com/intuit/karate/issues/1202#issuecomment-653632397

[image]

The result of `karate.match()` will return a JSON in the form `{ pass: '#boolean', message: '#string' }`

If none of the above options work - that means you are doing something *really* complicated, so [write Java interop / code](https://github.com/intuit/karate#calling-java) to handle this

For those who still insist on random behavior and conditional logic in UI tests, refer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/76701268/143475

Comment: I want to check for a key name in some JSON and then do assertion only if the key is present in json, for which I want to use _match_ statement. So I want to use this kind of conditional statement. I will make use of above example by having updated version of karate. Thank you.

Comment: * if (response != [] || '') karate.call('/features/PASE/helper/ServiceAddressessHelper.feature@BaseScenarioServiceAddressess5')

This is ServiceAddressessHelper.feature file

    Feature: Helper Feature
      
       @BaseScenarioServiceAddressess5
       Scenario: Helper scenario
       * match each response == expectedResponseServiceAddressess

This is not working. I am not able to figure it out. How to pass 'response' from test feature file