# AssertAll functionality in Karate Framework

Tags: karate

We have assertall() in testNG which is used to execute all assert statements without exiting testcase on failing of any of the assert.
Do we have anything like this in Karate??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No we don't and we feel it is not needed.

EDIT: maybe you were looking for this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/54108755/143475

So yes, if you use a data-driven `Scenario Outline` or [`call` in a loop](https://github.com/intuit/karate#data-driven-features) - a failure in one loop iteration will not stop the execution of others. So you can re-factor your test into that shape if it makes sense.

Note that there are many ways you can use [`conditional logic`](https://github.com/intuit/karate#conditional-logic) to get the same effect.