# Can anyone explain how to get all the mismatch between two responses in karate?

Tags: json, testing, karate

Like if I have two JSON as below and I want to check the mismatch between those

JSON 1:

```js
{
  name:'john',
  contact:'123',
  country:'america'
}
```

JSON 2:

```js
{
  name:'vishal',
  contact:'123',
  country:'India'
}
```

Now it will return me with the mismatch between name and country not only the name?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No this is not supported. We feel this is not needed, because in your regular CI runs  you only care if the test passed or failed, and you see the details in the log.

Also note that you can simulate this if you really want using a `Scenario Outline`: https://stackoverflow.com/a/54108755/143475

Finally, if you care so much about this, kindly contribute code, this is open-source after all.

EDIT: you can easily do this by iterating over keys. Here is the code:

EDIT2: Setting up data via a `Background` is no longer supported in version 1.3.0 onwards, please look at the `@setup` tag: https://github.com/karatelabs/karate#setup

```
Feature:

Background:
* def json1 = { name: 'john', contact: '123', country: 'america' }
* def json2 = { name: 'vishal', contact: '123', country: 'India' }
* def keys = karate.keysOf(json1)
* def data = karate.mapWithKey(keys, 'key')

Scenario Outline: <key>
* match (json1[key]) == json2[key]

Examples:
| data |
```

And here is the report:

[image]