# How to use Karate continueOnStepFailure to assert each Json field values

Tags: json, match, karate

The goal is to do soft assertion on each JSON field.

```
    * def KAFKA_TOPIC = "topic1"
    * def kafkaExpected = {field1:"value1",field2:"value2",field3:"value3"}
    * def kafkaActual = {"topic1":[{field1:"value1",field2:"x",field3:"y"}]}

    * configure continueOnStepFailure = { enabled: true, continueAfter: false, keywords: ['match'] }

    * match (kafkaActual[KAFKA_TOPIC]) == ['#(kafkaExpected)'] <-- do we have one-liner like this to do soft assertions on all fields?

    * configure continueOnStepFailure = false

Output:
$[0].field2 | not equal (STRING:STRING)
      'x'
      'value2'
```

Instead of doing it 1 by 1.

```
    * match (kafkaActual[KAFKA_TOPIC])[0].field1 == kafkaExpected.field1
    * match (kafkaActual[KAFKA_TOPIC])[0].field2 == kafkaExpected.field2
    * match (kafkaActual[KAFKA_TOPIC])[0].field3 == kafkaExpected.field3

Output:
match failed: EQUALS
  $ | not equal (STRING:STRING)
  'x'
  'value2'
match failed: EQUALS
  $ | not equal (STRING:STRING)
  'y'
  'value3'
```

And whats weird is that on terminal logs it only printed one assertion, either on both approach.

```
  $ | not equal (STRING:STRING)
  'y'
  'value3'
```

[image]
[image]

Trying to use Karate.forEach but seems like not the right path.
[image]

Comment: making sure you read this, that may answer some, if not all questions here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/54108755/143475

Comment: thanks for the link but in this case I dont want to use scenario outline to loop as well as table as the data is dynamic.
I just want toop in each json field and validate with soft assertion.

Im thinking karate.forEach but seems like not the right path.

Comment: @PeterThomas do we have plans to implement a one-liner for this?
something like match response contains json or a list  but with soft assertion enabled?

Comment: no we don't. I request you to please think about this. is this really the most important thing you need to be happy with your test automation ? I've written a lot about my opinion at the link. finally, you are most welcome to contribute code to improve things, this is all open-source.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found a solution from this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54107517/is-it-possible-to-do-soft-assertion-in-the-karate/54108755#54108755) provided by Peter. I just need to transform the JSON to list of key, value format and use it as data source.

```
From:
{field1:"value1",field2:"value2",field3:"value3"}

Transformed To: 
[{key:"field1",value:"value1"},{key:"field2",value:"value2"},{key:"field3",value:"value3"}]
```

Function used and usage:

```
 * def input = INPUT
 * def func = 
  """
    function(obj){
      var output = [];
      for (var i in obj) {
        output.push({key: i, value: obj[i]});
      }
      return output
    }
  """

    * json kafkaAttributes = func(input)
    * configure continueOnStepFailure = { enabled: true, continueAfter: false, keywords: ['match'] }
    * karate.call('kafka.feature@validateFieldsAndValues',kafkaAttributes) 
    * configure continueOnStepFailure = false

@validateFieldsAndValues
Scenario:
    * match (response[KAFKA_TOPIC][0][key]) contains value
```