# karate configure continueOnStepFailure does not work when call feature from file

Tags: karate

#poc.feature

```
Feature: POC

  @Test1
  Scenario: Test1

    * configure continueOnStepFailure = { enabled : true, continueAfter: true, keywords : ['match']}

    * def equal1 = 'bbb'
    * def notEqual1 = 'ccc'
    * def equal2 = 'bbb'
    * match equal1 == notEqual1
    * call read('./poc.feature@Test2')


  @Test2
  Scenario: Test2
    * match  equal1 == equal2

  @Test3
  Scenario: Test3
    * def result = call read('./poc.feature@Test1')
    * call read('./poc.feature@Test2')
```

#Run @Test3, it does not continue run line "* call read('./poc.feature@Test2')"

Comment: see my comment here: https://stackoverflow.com/q/73824475/143475

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.