# How to do conditional Karate abort based on response

Tags: karate

We are trying to abort scenario if there is a failure with specific error response caused by another team's code.

Case example for this is that we want to abort the test if we received error

`errors: [message: 'Data is not deployed....Etc etc']`

We know that we can use karate.abort(), however on the documentation we only see example based on status code:
`* if (responseStatus == 404) karate.abort()`

I wonder if it is possible for us to do something like

`* if (response.errors[0].message contains 'Data is not deployed') karate.abort()`

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

For anyone facing similar situation (optional abort), we solve it using this:

```
* if (response.errors!= null && response.errors[0].message.indexOf('Error Message') > -1) karate.abort()
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it has to be pure JS.

```
* if (response.errors[0].message.includes('Data is not deployed')) karate.abort()
```

Comment: Hi Peter! I tried the above but I received an error instead:

`javascript evaluation failed: if (response.errors[0].message.includes('Data is not deployed')) karate.abort(), TypeError: response.errors[0].message.includes is not a function`

Comment: Hi Peter. Thanks a lot! I solved it by using `.indexOf` instead of `.includes`. Cheers