# Change type from string to float/double for a key value of any json object in an array

Tags: karate

i have a json as follows:

```
* def first = [{"country":"X","code":"XY","cityName":"XYZN","city":"XYZ","timezone":"XYZT","latitude":"57.0928","name":"XYZN","longitude":"9.8492"}, {"country":"A","code":"AB","cityName":"ABCN","city":"ABC","timezone":"ABCT","latitude":"1.234","name":"ABCN","longitude":"29.8482"}]

def second = [{"country":"X","code":"XY","cityName":"XYZN","city":"XYZ","timezone":"XYZT","latitude":57.0928,"name":"XYZN","longitude":9.8492}, {"country":"A","code":"AB","cityName":"ABCN","city":"ABC","timezone":"ABCT","latitude":1.234,"name":"ABCN","longitude":29.8482}]
```

i want to compare these two, but its failing because the first json has longitude and latitude as string while second json has them as numbers.

Also, i dont want to change second json and has to be used as it is.

Please suggest how can i change the type from string to number in first?
I tried https://github.com/intuit/karate#floats-and-integers

but it didnt work out for object array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Sample Code:**

```
Feature:

Scenario:
    * def first = [{"country":"X","code":"XY","cityName":"XYZN","city":"XYZ","timezone":"XYZT","latitude":"57.0928","name":"XYZN","longitude":"9.8492"}, {"country":"A","code":"AB","cityName":"ABCN","city":"ABC","timezone":"ABCT","latitude":"1.234","name":"ABCN","longitude":"29.8482"}]

    * def second = [{"country":"X","code":"XY","cityName":"XYZN","city":"XYZ","timezone":"XYZT","latitude":57.0928,"name":"XYZN","longitude":9.8492}, {"country":"A","code":"AB","cityName":"ABCN","city":"ABC","timezone":"ABCT","latitude":1.234,"name":"ABCN","longitude":29.8482}]

    * def first_formatted = []
    * def fun = function(x){x.latitude = Number(x.latitude); x.longitude = Number(x.longitude); karate.appendTo(first_formatted, x); }
    * karate.forEach(first, fun)
    * print first_formatted
    * match first_formatted == second
```

Comment: Also, is there a way out that we can write the whole of the above code in an if condition?@Neodawn

Comment: @user1873274 https://stackoverflow.com/a/50350442/442595