# How to write multiple statements under if section in karate?

Tags: karate

Like I have do to some steps if some condition comes true how can I write multiple steps in if statement?

```
* if(responseStatus == 200) call myfunction
```

and after that I have to add one more statement under this "if" how will I add that?

Comment: @PeterThomas sorry forgot .Done

Answer (score 1, accepted):

a) use a JS function `* if(responseStatus == 200) myFunction()`

b) use `eval`

```
* eval
"""
if (condition) {
   // blah
   // blah
}
"""
```

For more ideas, read this please: https://stackoverflow.com/a/50350442/143475