# Schema validation in the Scenario

Tags: netty, karate

I'd like to have a single Scenario in my mock service to check for all possible schema issues, so I tried defining my schema in the background like this: `* def mySchema = {place: { id: '#string',},id: '#string',number: '#number'}`
then in my Scenario I tried this: `Scenario: pathMatches('my/api/path') && !karate.match(mySchema).pass`  but it threw this error: `java.lang.RuntimeException: syntax error, expected '==' for match`  Clearly my syntax is off.  What's the right way to write this?

Comment: this is a good reference for `match()` https://stackoverflow.com/a/50350442/143475

Comment: Here's what I ended up with: `!karate.match("request == mySchema").pass` which doesn't error, but it seems to match on what I believe is a request with the proper schema. `{"place": {"id": "anID"},"id": "anID","number": 10}`