# Schema Matching in Scenarios

Tags: netty, karate

I'm trying to use karate.match() to check the schema on a request in the Scenario.

Here's a sample schema I'm declaring in my Background:

```
* def mySchema = {place: { id: '#string',},id: '#string',number: '#number'}
```

I asked here about how to to match the full schema: [Schema validation in the Scenario](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64505413/schema-validation-in-the-scenario)

It was suggested that this was a duplicate, and that this reference for matching would do the trick: [Is it possible to use karate 'match' inside conditional statement?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50348629/is-it-possible-to-use-karate-match-inside-conditional-statement/50350442#50350442)

I'm still having trouble, and I don't think that the reference suggested applied in my case, because it seems to talk only about using match in a test, but the syntax seems to be different when used in a Scenario.

For instance, I decided to try to only match one part of my schema to just make sure I was using the correct syntax. I sent this request:

```
{"place": {"id": "someID"},"id": "someOtherID","number": 10}
```

I decided to try to match on the `number` value.

This is my Scenario:

```
Scenario: pathMatches('my/api/path') && !karate.match("request contains { number: '#number'}").pass
```

I also tried

```
!karate.match("each number =='#number'}").pass
```

bit neither work as intended.  I think in my request the `number` key value is a number.  That being the case, I'd expect the `!` to cause this scenario to be skipped, but it's not, which leads me to believe my schema match syntax isn't correct.

I appreciate any help.

Answer (score 1):

Sorry your question is hard to read, so I suggest you follow this process if you really want help: https://github.com/intuit/karate/wiki/How-to-Submit-an-Issue - and who knows, maybe it is a bug - and you can help up improve the framework.

I have certainly never tried these extreme matches in mocks, and I really wonder why this is needed. Karate is a "mock" not a full-blown server-side framework. BTW we will add a new way to do mocks in the future / 1.0

That said, 2 tips:

- as I said in a previous answer, try using functions set up in the `Background, fall-back to "brute force" JS if needed
- keep in mind that you don't need to do all the work in the `Scenario` expression. Once within the "body" of the `Scenario` you can use JS to do if-then-else kind of logic

Comment: Hey, fair enough!  If I read you correctly, your advice is, #1 evaluate if this kind of matching is actually needed, given this is a mock, #2 if it is, try to do it in JS functions declared in the Background, or #3 try to do it in the body of the Scenario?  For #3, would that mean having maybe 1 scenario to match my path then have conditional logic in the scenario body to decide which feature to run?

Comment: @ScottMacDonald yeah you could call another feature in theory for #3 but I would try to manage with some JS. do consider submitting an example, just to make sure we fix any problems, I really wonder now if `match()` would work outside the body

Answer (score 0):

After a lot of tooling around I was able to make progress on this when I realized the main problem was with me and how I was sending the request. The major issue was that Postman was sending the request as a GraphQL query.  I'm new to Postman, but it's a bit of dumb-dumb mistake.  Here's hoping someone else can learn from my mistake!