# Karate API : How to assert a json/response node value which returns null or an array object for different data

Tags: karate

I've got a request that returns a response node(**itemCanBe**) value in two possible ways, depending on the 'itemNum'. How do I assert this ? below attempt is not working

```
* match res..itemCanBe == null || res..itemCanBe[*] contains ['Colgate']
```

**itemCanBe returning null**

```
{
"itemDetails": {
    "1234": {
        "itemNum": "1234",
        "itemCanBe": null
    }
  }
}
```

**itemCanBe returning array**

```
{
"itemDetails": {
    "4567": {
        "itemNum": "4567",
        "itemCanBe": [
            "Colgate",
            "Sensodine"
        ]
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will actually work:

```
* def temp = get[0] response..itemCanBe
* match temp == '##[]'
```

Also refer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/50350442/143475

Answer (score 2):

See this thread for details: https://github.com/intuit/karate/issues/1202#issuecomment-653632397
This should be good enough to solve your problem.