# Expression with Array placeholder in the filter part of JsonPath using karate

Tags: karate

I am trying to filter response and i would like to accept multiple matches. Found that jsonPath has "in" operator to match value on the left side with array elements on the right.
String concatenation is working in jsonPath query strings, but how can I add array?

```
 * def my_array = ["a","b"]
 * def resp = karate.jsonPath(response, "$.content[?(@.smthing in my_array)]" )
```

As a workaround i can use regexp instead of array. But it is just to much effort.... :(

```
* queryString = ""
* def func = function(x){queryString += x +"|";}
* karate.forEach(my_array,func)
* def trunc = function( ) { queryString = queryString.substring(0, queryString.length()-1) }
* trunc()
* def resp = karate.jsonPath(response, "$.content[?(@.smthing =~ /'+queryString +'/)]" )
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For complex cases like this, I recommend using `karate.filter()`: https://github.com/intuit/karate#json-transforms

```
* def myArray = ['a', 'b']
* def fun = function(x){ return myArray.includes(x) }
* def response = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']
* match karate.filter(response, fun) == ['a', 'b']
```

Comment: So i try 
    * def types = ["a","b"]
    * def func = function(x){return types.includes(x.type); }
    * def filteredByTypes = karate.filter(response.content, func )
but i get an error message : 
listHesMessagesForMeter.feature:25 - evaluation (js) failed: karate.filter(response.content, func ), javax.script.ScriptException: TypeError: types.includes is not a function in <eval> at line number 1
stack trace: jdk.nashorn.api.scripting.NashornScriptEngine.throwAsScriptException(NashornScriptEngine.java:470)
Is it because of version 0.9.6?

Comment: @MiklosBalazsi yes. switch to 1.0 else use any custom JS that achieves the same thing. you can use this as a reference: https://stackoverflow.com/a/50350442/143475

Comment: Thank you. 
Yes. It is working with array.prototype.indexOf()
* def func = function(x){return types.indexOf(x.type) !== -1;}