# Nested if in karate?

Tags: ui-automation, karate

The need is to assert roles and fail the test script for few roles if the buttons are not disabled for them.
For which I tried performing steps similar to the following:

```
   * assert (role=="DM"||role=="RM"||role=="AVP")
   * eval if((role=="DM"||role=="AVP")? read('classpath:extraFeature.feature@checkIfDisabled') : print "options disabled... proceeding further!"
```

Here I am calling a scenario with tag @checkIfDisabled for the functionality which contains :

```
* if(exists(#listButton)) karate.fail("Options are enabled... Cannot proceed further! ")
```

I feel calling a different feature file for this little thing is not worth it. Moreover that as well is not working as expected. Nested if would've been a solution to this. If not or I am wrong with the approach please help me with something that can add to the logic.

I also tried storing the above called scenario code into a variable and call it.

```
* def fun = if(exists(#listButton)) karate.fail("Options are enabled... Cannot proceed further! ")
* call fun
```

But the error statement was something like, "this variable is not callable." Which I understand is something wrong from my side. But some hit and trials I did in search of an alternative to nested if. Any suggestions or way to deal this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `eval` and then delegate to pure JS like this:

```
* eval
"""
if (exists('#listButton')) karate.fail('blah')
else if (someCondition) {
  // do something
}
"""
```

And even a JS `switch case` can be used if you want !

If this doesn't help, I'll leave you with this answer and no other suggestions: https://stackoverflow.com/a/50350442/143475

Let me know what works though !