# Karate: Multiline afterScenario with assertions

Tags: karate

**I have the next code:**

```
* def deleteCallResult = call read('classpath:somepath@deleteCall') { id: #(id) }
Then match deleteCallResult.responseStatus == 204

* def getCallResult = call read('classpath:somepath@getCall') { id: #(id) }
Then match getCallResult.responseStatus == 404
Then match getCallResult.response.title == "Not Found"
```

**And would like to put it in afterScenario snippet (without moving it into a separate feature file):**

```
* configure afterScenario =
"""
function(){ ... }
"""
```

**Does Karate syntax allow to do it?** Did not find examples

Answer (score 0):

You *may* be able to do this if you use the JavaScript `match` syntax explained here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/50350442/143475

And you can try to call a `@ignore` `Scenario` in the same feature. The line below is JS. There is an [improvement to this](https://github.com/karatelabs/karate/issues/1499) that will be in the next version.

```
karate.call('same.feature', { some: 'arg' });
```

But consider what you are asking as not supported. Note that trying to write "clever" tests like this typically [lands you in trouble](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54126724/143475). It is recommended that you keep your main test flows simple.