# Check for attribute value from JSON response

Tags: karate

I am trying to validate the below conditions in the sample response

1. Based on `subjectType` attribute if it is either `Person` or `Organization`.
2. If `subjectType` is Person, check if it has a `birthDate` attribute

Sample response:

```
{ 
 "subject": "ABC",    
 "subjectType": "Person",    
 "birthDate": "1951-03-07"
}, 
{ 
 "subject": "ABC",    
 "subjectType": "Organization"    
}
```

I tried this, but no luck.

```
def expected = {subjectType: 'Person', birthDate: '#present'}

def schema = { subjectType: '#? _ == "Person" || _ == "Organization"', birthDate: '#($.subjectType == "Person" ? "#present" : "#present")' }

match expected == schema
```

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

There are many answers that give you solutions, please start here:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/50350442/143475

Since I just came up with a new idea to solve this, I'm posting it below. Note that there is no right answer, and there are many, many ways to do what you want.

```
* def schemas = 
"""
{
  Person: { subject: '#string', subjectType: 'Person', birthDate: '#string' },
  Organization: { subject: '#string', subjectType: 'Organization' }
}
"""
* def response = { "subject": "ABC", "subjectType": "Person", "birthDate": "1951-03-07" }
* def expected = schemas[response.subjectType]
* match response == expected
```

Also search slack overflow if you want to validate dates later.

Comment: Great! The above one worked, but how can I assert the response dynamically.? Above u have defined the response