# Does Karate support If Else with Match in the same block

Tags: conditional-statements, karate

I am trying to do a If Else condition on one of the scenarios that i encountered which requires the Match to be performed. Currently i have it handled via a Karate.call() with both the true and false condition and doing the matches there but it would be shorter for me to have it inline. I know that its not recommended to have conditional logic but this is an exception

```
**Current Implementation**
* def result = (response.status == 200) ? karate.call('listinPage.feature@FilterValidationPositive', {a: response, b:dbRows}) : karate.call('listinPage.feature@FilterValidationNegative', {a: response, b:dbRows})

**Desired**
Something along :
if (response.status == 200) match response.comment == 'xyz' else match response.comment == 'abc'
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `eval` keyword for multi-line JS blocks:

```
* def value = 'before'
* eval
"""
if (value == 'before') {
  value = 'after'
}
"""
* match value == 'after'
```

But please read this also: https://stackoverflow.com/a/50350442/143475