# Karate | Can we set payload based on status code condition

Tags: api, automation, karate

We have a post request as below
'''
{
Parameter : "name"
col : 1
}
'''

if the status code is 200 then do nothing, if status code is 400, then
set value : "test" in the above payload as below and send again.

'''
{
Parameter : "name"
col : 1
value : "test"
}
'''

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes.

```
* if (responseStatus == 200) karate.abort()
* request { second: 'time' }
* method post
```

If you want more ideas and also why you shouldn't do these kinds of "clever" tests, read this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/50350442/143475