# How to change key part of query string dynamically in karate

Tags: karate

I have the below requirement where I need to dynamically change the key-value pair of the query string, but I am able to dynamically change the value of the query parameter but not the key part. It is taking the text value like 'paramName' in the request.

- string reqBody = version == 'v2' ? 'ABC' : 'DEF'
- string paramName = version == 'v2' ? 'json_body' : 'proto_body'
- param paramName = reqBody

GET https://test.apis.com/sample?paramName=ABC
or
GET https://test.apis.com/sample?paramName=DEF

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you need dynamic param names, use `params`: https://github.com/karatelabs/karate#params

```
* def temp = version == 'v2' ? { json_body: 'ABC' } : { proto_body: 'DEF' }
* params temp
```

If you still have questions, read this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/50350442/143475