# How to assert a list in which each value should be one the values of the expected list?

Tags: karate

I am trying to assert a list using **match contains any, match each** but it is not working.

- **def actualList = ["CABLE_MODEM","SET_TOP_BOX","SET_TOP_BOX","CABLE_MODEM","CBE"]**
- **def expectedList = ["CABLE_CARD","SET_TOP_BOX","CABLE_MODEM","MTA","OTHER","IP_SET_TOP_BOX"]**
- **match each actualList contains any expectedList**

Basically, every value of the **actualList** should be **any one** of the **expectedList** value. But it is directly comparing the first value of the 2 lists. Kindly help me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure I understand the question. But sometimes these crazy assertions are best done in JS:

```
* def actualList = ["CABLE_MODEM","SET_TOP_BOX","SET_TOP_BOX","CABLE_MODEM","CBE"]
* def expectedList = ["CABLE_CARD","SET_TOP_BOX","CABLE_MODEM","MTA","OTHER","IP_SET_TOP_BOX"]
* def unexpected = actualList.filter(x => !expectedList.includes(x))
* match unexpected == []
```

Please take the help of a friend who knows JS if the above is not clear.

EDIT: for completeness, here's the "karate style" way to solve this. For more complex custom checks, [`karate.match()`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50350442/143475) can be used.

```
* def valid = function(x){ return expectedList.includes(x) }
* match each actualList == '#? valid(_)'
```