# how to count a value in a list based on the same value in another list. and the both are dynamic when i get the response in karate

Tags: karate

list 1 ["ART - Run and Support","ART - Run and Support","Clt group","Clt group"]
list 2 ["ART - Run and Support","Clt group",]

I want to take the 1st value in list2 and count the occurrences in list 1.
"ART - Run and Support" = 2
I was able to take for 1 value, not sure how to pass this in loop. Please do help.

```
* def condition = function(x){ return x == "Application Development" }
* def output = karate.filter(Total_List_AssignmentGroup, condition).length
* print output
```

I was able to take for 1 value, not sure how to pass this in loop. Please do help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was a fun problem ! Here is the solution, and believe it or not it is just one line:

```
* def list1 = ["ART - Run and Support", "ART - Run and Support", "Clt group", "Clt group"]
* def list2 = ["ART - Run and Support", "Clt group"]
* def results = list2.map(x => ({ name: x, count: list1.filter(y => x === y).length }))
* print results
```

Which gives you:

```
[
  {
    "name": "ART - Run and Support",
    "count": 2
  },
  {
    "name": "Clt group",
    "count": 2
  }
]
```

This is just using JavaScript array operations such as `map()` and `filter()`

Comment: Hi Peter, Thank you for the response.
I tried this, I get <eval> error at x=>,
Can you help in this.

Comment: @user20485356 I cut and pasted those exact 4 lines and it works perfectly. maybe you are on an old version of karate. I recommend you upgrade. or you can try using "old style" syntax, refer this for how: https://stackoverflow.com/a/73407959/143475

if still stuck, follow this process: https://github.com/karatelabs/karate/wiki/How-to-Submit-an-Issue