Execute different api based on conditional statement
Is there a way to execute apis based on condition?
Scenario:

And path 'path1'
And request {}
When method post
Then status 200

{execute get1 if condition is true and execute get2 when condition is false} 
#get1
And path 'path2'
When method get
Then status 200

#get2
And path 'path3'
When method get
Then status 200

#get3
And path 'path4'
When method get
Then status 200

I have tried conditional statements using ternary operator but I am unsure how to execute a block of code there.

Please don't do this. Reasons are explained here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/54126724/143475
If you insist, refer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/50350442/143475
